# Logic inside ${ } while building a string in Express.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'd like to loop through an object and output values for each while generating a string.

How can I accomplish something like this:

```
const body = `
<h1>Values</h1>
    ${
     for (value in values) {
      return `<h2>Individual value: ${values[value].valueInt}</h2>`
     }
    }
`;
```

It's for generating an email.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't want much logic in there and would more go for something like let body = '<h1>Values</h1>'; values.map((value) => { body += `<h2>Individual value: ${value}</h2>`; });

Comment: Any way to remove the commas that are generated in between instances with that method?

Answer (score 0):

you can use map for that

```
const body = `<h1>Values</h1>${values.map(value => `<h2>Individual value: ${value}</h2>`)}`;
```

Comment: Any way to remove the comma between instances?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the general shape of the values object something like this should work:

```
const body = `<h1>Values</h1>${
    Object.values(values)
        .map(value => `<h2>Individual value: ${value.valueInt}</h2>`)
        .join('')
}`;
```

An example of the values object would help.